# Multiple spannableString.setSpan in a loop

Tags: android, kotlin, spannablestring, spannablestringbuilder

I'm creating a calculator app using Kotlin. I want to highlight the operation characters (+, -, *, /) by making their color blue.
The array operationsInStrings is filled with indexes of characters from string that I wish to change the color to blue. Only the last member of the array turns to blue color
[Emulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7codw.png). I tried using both spannableString and SpannableStringBuilder, but I'm probably doing something wrong as I'm new to the language. The array is filled correctly, as I tested it.
[Function code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXZ2m.png)

Answer (score 0):

A single span can only have one location within a SpannableString or SpannableStringBuilder. To color multiple ranges, you need to create a different span for each range.